# Table name 'tblStudent' is not valid. The table name is null or empty; or the table name contains the keywords SET, FMTONLY, and OFF

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-ce

I am using VS2010, SQL Server CE, SQL Server 2008 R2, WCF.

I have created a sample to sync 125 tables from local `*.sdf` file to server database using WCF.

It is working fine if WCF is hosted on my local machine, but when I host it on remote server then its raising the following error:

> *Table name 'tblStudent' is not valid. This might be caused by one or
>   more of the following issues:  unable to find a SyncAdapter for the
>   specified SyncTable; the table name is null or empty; or the table
>   name contains the keywords SET, FMTONLY, and OFF.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing when WCF is hosted on a different computer you are not connected to the correct SQL Server CE Instance.  What is your connection string and are you sure you are going to the remote instance of Windows CE and that instance accepts external connections?

Comment: Actually I am using Microsoft Synchronization Framework 2.1 for Synchronizing local SQLCE 4.0 database to Remote SQL Server 2008 R2 database. I have used SqlCeClientSyncProvider as a local provied and ServerSyncProvider (DBServerSyncProvider) for server provider.  I have refered this link : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlblog/archive/2010/04/19/step-by-step-n-tier-configuration-of-sync-services-for-ado-net-2-0.aspx